# Android url override doesn't work on redirect

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, url-scheme

I have a url that I am overriding in my Android App.  Clicking a link from an email to that link pops up the `Intent Chooser` dialog ("Complete this using").  However clicking the same link (in an `<a>` tag) from within Chrome (on Android 4) redirects me to that url, and doesn't offer the `Intent Chooser`.

If I replace the link in the `<a>` tag with a link to the Google Play Store (`https://play.google.com`) then clicking the link pops up the `Intent Chooser` again.

Is there something special with the Google Play Store and Chrome, or have I done something wrong configuring my url?  Is there something I can do in html to make this work?

Here's the `<intent-filter>`

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="..."
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data android:scheme="https"
              android:host="www.example.com"
            />
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
            />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

(Redirecting to the url also does not pop up the `Intent Chooser` dialog, but I figured my situation above more pointedly expresses my issue.)

Also of note, I am fairly certain this was all working while my domain was down.  As soon as my domain came online this stopped working.  This could be a figment of my imagination as I wasn't 100% focused on this problem at the time.

Is it possible that Chrome treats Google Play Store urls special, otherwise it waits for a non-200 response from a url before opening the `Intent Chooser`?

Comment: What version of Android are you running? Wondering if it's not related to this bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113140

Comment: That's a good find.  I am running 4.2.2 I also found this bug that might be related: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170925 but my code diverged from a place that's easy to test it because I had to get it out the door.  I'll set up a test soon.

Comment: @AlexFlorescu if you write up an answer explaining that it's one of these bugs (I've also posted a new bug that isn't closed: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=230104) I'll mark your answer correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could very well be a real/known bug.

The one I suggested (but which is now closed so it seems would be fixed for version you're trying with): 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113140

Found/opened by @xbakesk:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170925
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=230104

If any other bugs found, just let me know in the comments and I will add, or edit my answer directly. If bugs get closed, I'll also try to update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I tinkered with this quite a bit and it may be easier to just show you a method that works.  This works on a device with 2.3.4 and a device with 4.2.2, so I'm thinking it will work on most devices.

Here's my intent filter from the manifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="realsimpleapps.com" android:pathPrefix="/acv/" />
</intent-filter>
```

Here's my html file:

```
<a href="http://realsimpleapps.com/acv/aThing">Click Me!</a>
```

And in my Main activity I use this to grab whatever I have "aThing" (above) set to:

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
if (data != null) {
    List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
    if (params != null) {
        Log.d(tag, "Param 0: " + params.get(0));
    }
}
```

Get that working, then add the second data element to the intent filter.  If it still works after that, you should be set.

Let us know how it goes.

db

Comment: I pulled it down to just one `<data>` element, and I have exactly the same situation.  Clicking a link (outside of Chrome) there is an Intent Chooser dialog that pops open offering my app as a resolution to the intent.  If I click a link from with-in Chrome, there is never an Intent Chooser dialog, Chrome just handles the url.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can add more than one data element to an intent filter. I would use two different intent filters for different schemes.

If you have control on the url which is on the webpage, you can change the http to your own custom protocol so your app will open instead of prompting along the web browser.

Comment: Per this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html you can have multiple `<data>`, they just get combined, although I will admit in a not very verbosely documented way.  That doesn't change anything in the behavior described.  As for your second point, in my case overriding http is the requirement.