# How to handle Oauth2 redirect (custom URL scheme) in android

Tags: android, webview, url-scheme

I want to start new activity or execute some code when user redirected from successful login in android. I am using webview to provide login page, it will redirect to custom url scheme such as `myapp://something`. I am using intent filter to identify the redirection. But webview displays `page not found` in android version 4.3 and `net: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` in 5. Is it because of [URL scheme bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181186) or something else? (I am not using actual redirection yet, but I have tried with anchor tag and javascript `window.location`)

How can I achieve this? Without using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` in webview client. I want to accept custom URL scheme since back end can not be changed.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522003/android-redirect-to-a-url-with-my-custom-scheme-doesnt-work?rq=1